# JavaFX - what do people think?

Tags: java, javafx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are your feelings on JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533895/what-are-your-feelings-on-javafx)

Hi folks,

I'm learning Java at the moment, would say I'm at intermediate level at the moment. I came across JavaFX so checked out the website. Well, it looks awesome! but I'd like to know what other people think. Maybe also a few tips on getting started?

Cheers,
Jonesy

Answer (score 3):

I think Oracle should work on implementing JavaFX on Android instead of suing Google over patents.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at it once but it seemed a little too fad-ish. I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761237/suggestions-for-declarative-gui-programming-in-java) about declarative GUI programming in the java world.

Answer (score 0):

There is some kind of interest in JavaFX's main proposal of a declarative (but non XML-ish) GUI. Aside that, the tendancy of the language to mimc ActionScript puzzles me a little. However, as it is an element of the java-sphere, it is perfectly possible to

- [Write JavaFX applications using Swing widgets](http://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/how_to_use_javafx_in)
- [Use JavaFX components from pure Java code](http://www.javafxgame.com/javafx-scene-swing-java/)

Notice it is even possible to mix Java/JavaFX code with others scripting languages, but it then becomes an improbable mess.