# JavaFX vs Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx

What exactly is JavaFX? We just started Java GUI and we are going to use Swing for our course. Now, I was looking up for some tutorials to assist me on YouTube and I downloaded some GUI videos only to find out that they are some JavaFX ones. So, what is this?

Comment: FX is just a new framework you can use to create graphical user interfaces; a newer alternative to Swing. FX supports styling your view with CSS, managing your model with XML (FXML) and controlling events in your application in Java. As for which one you should use, that's opinion based and isn't fit for this site. FX was intended to replace Swing, but Swing is still used quite a bit as you can probably notice

Comment: What are your requirements? You can't base the decision on the difference between JavaFX and Swing, but rather on what you need for your application.

Comment: You can start with [JavaFX version and “development patterns” questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23712845/1759128) and [What to know before starting to learn JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23628615/1759128) threads.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533895/what-are-your-feelings-on-javafx?s=8|51.7484

Answer (score 0):

You can read up about it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html

Start by downloading ensemble, it will get you started. I pick javaFX for my next java GUI app because I find it pretty cool. Swing is around because that's what everyone's used to and it will be popular for a while until more people check out javaFX. And yes JavaFX can replace swing.